# How to make a local notification go off in xcode?

Tags: ios, notifications, alarm

I am developing an app, where an local notification has to be triggered, when variables value if f.x. above 40.

I was thinking about using:

```
If(Myvalue > 40) {
    Notification triggers
}
```

But I don't know how to trigger the notification.

Could you please help me?

Comment: @mah, OP is asking about UILocalNotification, not how to use notifications from within the app.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should get you started using `UILocalNotification`:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate date];

localNotif.alertBody = @"Message body"
localNotif.alertAction = @"View Details";

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```